# Elastic Beanstalk running mod_wsgi Django app with multi processes causing 302 loop

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-wsgi

I have been investigating for a while now, and all the docs seem to say this is possible, but whenever I increase our `elastic beanstalk` `mod_wsgi` `NumProcesses` config above `1`, our admin site is inaccessible.

I have created a reduction where I tested with a default `django` app, and the behaviour is still present. I have also tried to replicate locally, however my `apache` and `mod_wsgi` config cannot replicate the issue.

Basically, what I am seeing, is that every attempted login, causes a `302 Found redirect` back to the login page. I have cleared the sessions out of the database, and I can confirm that the application creates a new entry during the login `POST`, but the user is still directed back to the login page (see config and logs below). We also have a load balancer and sticky sessions configured on the `Elastic Beanstalk` instance(s).

Here is the `python` contained config from our `.ebextensions`

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: site/settings/wsgi/__init__.py
    NumProcesses: 4
    NumThreads: 15
```

Here is the resulting `wsgi.conf` taken from the instance

```
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/site/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/site/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/site/settings/wsgi/__init__.py


<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=4 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is a grab of the `access_log` showing the redirect

```
::1 - - [05/Jun/2017:13:26:18 +0000] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [05/Jun/2017:13:26:18 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [05/Jun/2017:13:26:18 +0000] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1650
```

Now, the following set of configs and info is taken from my local installation.

```
# wsgi.conf

WSGIVerboseDebugging 'On'
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /Users/www/app/site/static/
<Directory /Users/www/app/site/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIProcessGroup _www
WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/www/app/site/settings/wsgi/__init__.py \
        process-group=_www


<Directory /Users/www/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess _www processes=4 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} group=_www user=_www \
  python-path=/Users/www/app:/usr/local/lib/python2.7 \
  home=/Users/www/app/site
</VirtualHost>
```

expected `access_log`

```
::1 - - [05/Jun/2017:23:27:48 +1000] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [05/Jun/2017:23:27:48 +1000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2783
```

The question I have, is why does one work, and one produce a loop? I can see an option on the `WSGIScriptAlias`, but that's not available on the `elastic beanstalk` config, and the documentation still says this is feasible. What am I missing here? Why does having multiple processes cause this issue?

*Extra Notes*

Failing `mod_wsgi` version `3.5`

Working `mod_wsgi` version `4.5.15`

I was also able to get my local `wsgi` app working with `python 3.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found a `Session data corrupted` entry in the `apache` `error_log`

Turns out, the code to generate the `SECRET_KEY` was randomly assigning one in production.

Meaning, when the request was passed to another process, the session key did not match, logging the user out and sending the back to the login page. Hence the `302 Found` loop.

Found this helpful [Django Login/Session Not Sticking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036831/django-login-session-not-sticking)